# Using React to either display login or logout button

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I want my homepage in React to either show the Login and Signup buttons if the user is not loggedIn, or show the Logout button only if the user is loggedIn.  I also have a title and description, but I only want that showing if the user hasn't logged in yet.

I'm using the following function in `auth.js`

```
  loggedIn() {
    const token = this.getToken();
    return !!token && !this.isTokenExpired(token);
  }
```

Then on my `Homepage.js`, I have

```
import React from "react";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
import { Container, Button, Grid } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Auth from "../utils/auth";

export default function Homepage() {
  function showNavigation() {
    if (Auth.loggedIn()) {
      return (
        <Grid columns={2}>
          <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Column>
              <Link to="/" onClick={() => Auth.logout()}>
                <Button.Group widths="2">
                  <Button >
                    Logout
                  </Button>
                </Button.Group>
              </Link>
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <Container text textAlign="center">
            <Grid columns={2}>
              <Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Column>
                  <Link to="/">
                    <Button.Group widths="2">
                      <Button>
                        Login
                      </Button>
                    </Button.Group>
                  </Link>
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column>
                  <Link to="/signup">
                    <Button.Group widths="2">
                      <Button>
                        Signup
                      </Button>
                    </Button.Group>
                  </Link>
                </Grid.Column>
              </Grid.Row>
            </Grid>
          </Container>
        </>
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
    <Container
       as="h1"
       content="Title Here"/>
          
    <Container
       as="h2"
       content="description" />
          {showNavigation()}
   </>
  )
}
```

But the `<Container>` with title and description and the login/signup buttons are showing up twice. How do I refactor this correctly?

Comment: Do you mind showing the component this is called from?

Comment: from ```app.js```. I'll add above.

Comment: nevermind. I just noticed I was calling ```<Homepage />``` in my ```app.js``` and this was duplicating the image.